# Report Viewer in MVC3

Tags: reportviewer

I have written a report in asp.net MVC 3 with the report viewer using a user control (ascx) in a partial View in the Report.cshtml(View).  I'm having a problem with report viewer control when I run the application.  When I have more than two pages and I want see the second or more page, I get "microsoft jscript runtime error '__eventtarget' is null or not an object".

The error is because there is postback.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to use the built in toolbar to navigate. (At least not without finding your own work around).

What I did was created my own bar right above my control and it simply sends an action ("First", "Last", "Next", "Previous") to an action on the controller to adjust the ReportViewer's CurrentPage Variable. (I keep tract of the current page through the session and set it in the user control ascx).